# Strange solution for fibonacci, explanation needed

Tags: javascript, algorithm, fibonacci

My first implementation of the fibonacci algorithm was:

```
function fibo(max, old = 0, curr = 1) {
  if( old === 0 && curr === 1 ) { console.log(curr) }
  if(curr + old < max) {
    console.log( curr + old);
    fibo(max, curr, old + curr);
  }
}

fibo(50);
```

I was playing with the fibonacci algorithm in javascript and I stumbled upon a strange but neater solution that I can't explain:

```
function fibo(max, old = 0, curr = old++) {
  if(curr + old < max) {
    console.log( curr + old);
    fibo(max, curr, old + curr);
  }
}

fibo(50);
```

why does this function display 1 1 2 .. and not 1 2 3 ... ?

Comment: Where does that `50` come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why does this function display 1 1 2 .. and not 1 2 3 ... ?

`old` is `0` until it gets to the initialization of the default parameter (on the first invocation), which increments it to `1` and sets the original value of `old` to `curr`.

So `old` is `1` and `curr` is `0` on the first call, and `1+0` is `1` for the first call, and then it will be `1+0` for the next call.

This is a little confusing, because on the first call, the `old` ends up being behind the `curr`, but the sum is of course the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I see it now

Comment: @Ben: Sorry, I was getting ahead of myself. I added a correction. The postifix `++` means that the original value is assigned to `curr`, so it's `0`. So on the next call, you get `1` for `old` and `0+1` for `curr`.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vdBajj?editors=1111 it displays 1 1 2 3 ... in the console

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I was really confused for a moment because your description seemed right by my console only seemed to give a single `1`, but then I noticed that it showed an count of 2 for that value toward the right.